# Multiple temporary variables in Vue JS template inside of v-for construction?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a construction like this:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <p>{{ f1(item).k1 }}</p>
  <p>{{ f1(item).k2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ f2(item).k3 }}</p>
  <p>{{ f2(item).k4 }}</p>
</div>
```

where `f1` and `f2` are the component's methods that return objects with the fields `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`. In this example the methods are called as many times as many keys I need in the template, that can be expensive.

Is there a way to store the results of calculations into variables `v1` and `v2` to prevent multiple calls?

I found a solution for one temporary variable:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :set="v1 = f1(item)">
  <p>{{ v1.k1 }}</p>
  <p>{{ v2.k2 }}</p>
</div>
```

but I couldn't generalize it for the case with two variables elegantly. Also I met the solutions to create a different component for the tag with `v-for` instead of `div` I used, it seems to be too complicated and bulky.

Comment: Are you saying both `f1` and `f2` return objects with `k1` through `k4` properties?

Comment: It does not matter. What matters is `f1` and `f2` are two completely different functions that I do not want to merge into one.

Comment: Do the objects returned have overlapping keys or not? I ask as it might make the answer a little neater

Answer (score 2):

It's almost universally a [bad idea to call methods from your template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods).

This is really what computed properties are for.

```js
computed: {
  calculatedItems () {
    return this.items.map(item => ({
      f1: this.f1(item),
      f2: this.f2(item)
    }))
  }
}
```

This will only execute when required (ie, if `items` changes). Now you can iterate this in your template without making any method calls

```html
<div v-for="item in calculatedItems">
  <p>{{ item.f1.k1 }}</p>
  <p>{{ item.f1.k2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ item.f2.k3 }}</p>
  <p>{{ item.f3.k4 }}</p>
</div>
```